# ALT-tab glitch on secondary user-account

Tags: 16.04, unity, application-switcher

On my main account, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> works just fine, however, I just created a second user, and the application switcher is completely messed up, there seem to be two interfaces displayed on top of each other, as can be seen in the image below:

[image: ALT-tab-glitch.png]

I already tried rebooting multiple times, but the problem remains.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: That looks like one or two redundant or misconfigured Compiz plug-ins. I don't have it myself but you can install and use *Compiz Config Settings Manager* (from the package `compizconfig-settings-manager`) to go through and review the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David Foerster, I resolved it:

I installed the Compiz Config Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

And then under `Window management`, I disabled the `Application Switcher` plugin.
Now it only shows the standard switcher.